# UIcollectionview cell animation effect that moves the collection frame horizontally

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. I have created a UIcollectionview that scrolls horizontally (one line).  If a user scroll very fast, I would like the last cell to pull with it the collection frame showing what is behind the frame. What I do not want is for the last cell to move from its place and should the collection background. I added a pan gesture to the collection view, and with the logic I put in place, I see that the collection frame moves before the last cell is reached. same if you scroll backward to reach the first cell. I am new at this and there got to be a easy way to do it.

```
- (IBAction)handleGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x/3,recognizer.view.center.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)

{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState  animations:^{
        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, recognizer.view.center.y);
    } completion:nil];
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
 {
    if ([gestureRecognizer isEqual:self.panGesture] && [otherGestureRecognizer isEqual:self.collectionview.panGestureRecognizer]){
        return YES;
}
return NO;
}

- (BOOL) gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if([gestureRecognizer isEqual:self.panGesture])
    {
    if(self.collectionview.contentOffset.x ==0)
        {
        return YES;
        }
    else if(self.collectionview.contentOffset.x >= (self.collectionview.contentSize.width - self.view.bounds.size.width))
        {
        return YES;
        }
    }
return NO;
}
```